# Create redirect URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is the real case, in the NewsNow.co.uk, there are many link of uptodate news from thousands of website. And the example for one of the news url:

> `http://newsnow.co.uk/A/471722742?-19721`

all the news url are formated like that, but when we click it, we will be brought to the real url, for ex:

> `http://www.abcactionnewsx.com/dpp/news/state/bla-bla`

anyone know how to achieve this efficiently ?

Comment: most of the url redirections uses .htaccess for url renaming for SEO purposes and neatness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done using a rewrite engine that is built into common webservers like Apache or Nginx.  These engines allow you to write rules that transform a url like the first one into something that would be better understood by your php pages.  For example, you could create rules that would turn your first link above into:

```
http://newsnow.co.uk/index.php?catagory=A&id=471722742&referrer=-19721
```

This is transparent to the user and they will only ever see the link they first typed in. You can then use the variables being passed in to perform whatever actions you desire.  In this case you might want to use the variables to perform some kind of database lookup to retrieve the actual destination that you are interested in.  Then it's just a question of performing a php redirect to the link in question.

Check out the following link for a very quick intro to Apache's rewriting capabilities (called mod_rewrite): http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/mod-rewrite-intro.html

Answer (score 2):

Store a table of 'internal' paths (the 'newsnow' urls) and the 'destination' urls in a database of some sort; sqlite3 would be a fine choice for smaller applcations.

You could hash the 'internal' paths if lookup time for specific strings was too slow in the database you chose.

When a request comes in, look it up in the database and send back a 302 response with the 'target' URL as the new location for the resource.

Comment: The first time you go to the site (ie without their cookies), they show you a splash page for 2 seconds before redirecting you. In that case they just display an html page, perhaps with a `meta refresh` header, eg `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=    http://www.abcactionnewsx.com/dpp/news/state/bla-bla">`. Consequent times the redirect is instantaneous so I'm guessing the `2` becomes `0` above.

Comment: @Fanis, ah, if they've got a splash of some sort, I bet you're right. It'd be easier to fiddle with that than handle two different kinds of responses based on presence/absence of Cookies.